# Assign a keyboard key to an image or link

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, keyboard, key

I'm trying to to trigger an onclick action with the keyboard. Javascript or jQuery.

I'm able to do it when people click on the images, but I want it to be simpler, like pressing keyboard keys without the use of CTRL, ALT or SHIFT.

It's for doing a piano.

Comment: What are you asking for exactly? Where is your code attempt?

Comment: I don't have any code attempt, I've been looking for a script, but none really seemed to do the job. I saw some with the CTRL or ALT key or even the "accesskey" in the img tag. Not used to use stack overflow, sorry.

Comment: Its cool man, next time just show your code attempt. We are here to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just bind an event that listens to keydown event.

```
$(window).on('keydown', function(e){
    // Do your thing.
    switch(e.which){
        case 13:
           alert('You pressed the enter key');
           // Or if you want to trigger click event already assigned to an image.
           $('img').trigger('click');
           break;
        ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [$.trigger function](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) in jQuery? Seems like you should be able to run `$("#image").trigger("click");` when the right key is pressed.